# Java HashMap get method null pointer exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, hashmap

My code is similar to the following:

```
public class A {
        private HashMap<Character, Boolean> myMap;

        public A() {
            myMap = new HashMap<Character, Boolean>();
            String mychars = "asdfzxcvqwer";
            for (char c : mychars.toCharArray())
                myMap.put(c, true);
        }

        public void doo(String input) {
            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
            for (char c : input.toCharArray()) {
                if (myMap.get(c))
                    output.append(c);
            }
        }
        //...
        //...
    }
```

Why am I getting a null pointer exception (NPE) at the line `if (myMap.get(c))`?

Comment: @talnicolas check his map declaration and also do is a reserved keyword in java, you cant use it as a method name

Comment: I typed out the code manually into SO -- apologies for both the errors. Thanks very much for the answers, everyone. I'll make the edits.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

If `c` is not contained in `myMap`, it will return `null`, which can't be unboxed as a `boolean`.

Try :

```
Boolean b = myMap.get(c);
if(b != null && b){
...
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Also, `HashMap myMap<Character, Boolean>` is a syntax error (should be `HashMap<Character, Boolean> myMap`), and you can't name methods `do`.

Answer (score 18):

If `myMap` doesn't contain a key that matches `c`, then `myMap.get(c)` will return null. In that case, when the JVM unboxes what it expects to be a `java.lang.Boolean` object into a `boolean` primitive to execute the condition, it founds a null object and therefore throws a `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

The following block is equivalent to what you have in your example and should make it easier to understand why you would have a `NullPointerException`:

```
if (((Boolean) myMap.get(c)).booleanValue())
```

I would re-write your original condition as:

```
if ( myMap.containsKey(c) )
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

Change

```
if ( myMap.get(c) )
```

to

```
if ( myMap.containsKey(c) && myMap.get(c))
```

Answer (score 3):

If there is no entity with required `Character` in map, then `map.get(key)` returns `null` and inside `if` statement it leads to `NullPointerException` throwing.

Answer (score 3):

A stab in the dark: is there an entry in your map for the particular character assigned to `c`? If there isn't, Java may be trying to unbox a null value...

Answer (score 3):

Changing this

```
for ( char c : input.toCharArray() )
{
  if ( myMap.get(c) )
     output.append(c);
}
```

For this

```
for ( char c : input.toCharArray() )
{
  if ( myMap.containsKey(c) )
     output.append(c);
}
```

Will make use of the map's defined method to check if a certain key is registered on the map. I'm leaving the `for` as it is, since you seem to want to check for a group of keys.

`myMap.get(c)` returns the value associated with that key, or `null` if the key is not registered.

As a side note, remember that if you use this method with custom objects you'll have to redefine the `hashcode` and `equals` methods.

Suggestion: I'm just suggesting this out of a remote idea I have, if it's not a correct interpretation of your code just ignore it. If your map only contains a boolean value to determine if certain value "is contained" or not, I strongly suggest you use a `HashSet` instead because a map is not doing any sense in that context.

Comment: Good answer, +1. Do you happen to know if `containsKey(c)` is faster than `get(c) != null`?

Comment: @durron597 Based on the implementation of both `containsKey` and `get`, actually there is a difference in performance if the key is null. `containsKey` calls the method `getEntry` who iterates over the entry set, as `get` does too (they're actually the same method, except `get` does a null check with the key and returns null if the key is null, while `getEntry` assigns a hash value of 0 if the submitted key is `null`, this particular case makes the difference).

Answer (score 2):

Your code is very messy.

- do is a reserved keyword, do not use it as a method name.
- a 'if' expression must return a boolean, not null.
- myMap's initialization is not correctly written

Here is a working version :

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class A {
    private HashMap<Character, Boolean> myMap;

    public A() {
        this.myMap = new HashMap<Character, Boolean>();
        String mychars = "asdfzxcvqwer";
        for ( char c : mychars.toCharArray() )
            myMap.put(c, true);
    }

    public String execute(String input) {
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        for ( char c : input.toCharArray() )
        {
            if ( this.myMap.get(c) != null )
                output.append(c);
        }
        return output.toString();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A test = new A();
        test.execute("abc");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use [apache.commons.lang3](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/BooleanUtils.html) which checks for `Boolean` and handles `null` check `BooleanUtils.isTrue(c)`

#### Explanation:

There's a general confusion where exactly the NPE is being thrown i.e. when `get()` is called on the map or when `if(...)` is performed.

Your map is declared as:

```
myMap = new HashMap<Character, Boolean>();
```

Which contains a primitive `boolean` wrapper class `Boolean` as a value to the map entry.

When you do:

```
if (myMap.get(c))
```

`myMap` which is a `HashMap` returns `null` when `get()` is invoked because a certain key is not present in the map. `null` is then unboxed to primitive `boolean` and that's where the **NPE** is being thrown not when you invoke `get()` by itself.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just handled it with a catch block , like so :

```
@PostMapping("/findAllLastExecutedApi")
    public ResponseEntity<Map<String,List<Results>>>findAllLastExecuted(@RequestBody Map<String,String> uuids) {
        try{ 
            // NPE is triggered here : 
            if(uuids.get("demoId").isEmpty()) {
                Map<String,List<Results>> badResults= Collections.singletonMap("Invalid demoId provided, is empty",null);
                log.error("Invalid demoId provided, is empty {}",uuids);
                return  ResponseEntity.ok(badResults);
            }

            Map<String,List<Results>> results =
                    this.service.findAll(uuids.get("demoId"));
            return ResponseEntity.ok(results);

        }catch (NullPointerException e){
            log.error("Invalid demoId provided, is null {}",uuids);
            throw new NullPointerException("Invalid demoId provided , is null");
        }
    }
```